# Syntax highlighting for rails server logs in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3

I know it's a long-shot, but I'm copy/pasting server logs into my text editor and it would greatly improve the reading experience if the logs were syntax-highlighted the same way they appear in the terminal.

Is this possible in Sublime Text 3?

(image for illustrative purposes)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [LogHighlight](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Log%20Highlight) plugin? It should work for every language.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I installed it, but it doesn't quite look right. example: https://i.imgur.com/l8A5T4c.png